# USPS Priority Mail API: Is the Days field business days?

Tags: usps

According to the [USPS Web Tools documentation](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/domestic-mail-service-standards-api.htm#_Toc456257907), this is a sample output of the Priority Mail time in transit API:

```
<PriorityMailResponse>
  <OriginZip>90201</OriginZip>
  <DestinationZip>21114</DestinationZip>
  <Days>4</Days>
</PriorityMailResponse>
```

The description of the Days tag just says "Numbers of days expected to deliver". Does this mean actual days or business days? Do I have to take weekends and holidays into account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming problem.

Comment: This is best answered by the documentation for that service, or via an inquiry to their support department.

Comment: I included the relevant part of the documentation in the question. Added a link for clarity.